# types conflict on Golang Api Kind Struct Creation

Tags: go, client-go, operator-sdk

I face an issue while creating types.go in client-go.

```
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
  namespace: sample-system
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 2.5.0
    replicas: 3
    listeners:
      plain:
        authentiation:
          type: scram-sha-512
      tls:
        authentiation:
          type: tls
```

As per below Kind **"Kafka"** ...

i have schema for Kafka Kind as below

```
// Kafka is the Schema for the kafkas API
type Kafka struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta   `json:",inline"`
    metav1.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty"`
    Spec   KafkaSpec   `json:"spec,omitempty"`
    Status KafkaStatus `json:"status,omitempty"`
}
```

while when i need to define Spec.kafka type

```
// KafkaSpec defines the desired state of KafkaBundle
type KafkaSpec struct {
    // INSERT ADDITIONAL SPEC FIELDS - desired state of cluster
    // Important: Run "make" to regenerate code after modifying this file
    Kafka          *Kafka      `json:"kafka"`
    
    // Foo is an example field of Kafka. Edit Kafka_types.go to remove/update
    Foo string `json:"foo,omitempty"`
}
```

i face issue of two kafka struct types.which is error.

Answer (score 0):

Your struct `Kafka` has a dependent struct `KafkaSpec` and your struct `KafkaSpec`depends upon struct `Kafka`. If you look into structs, you are creating a cyclic dependency, which might be a problem here. I would recommend following the below structs,

Main struct `Kafka`

```
// Kafka is the Schema for the kafkas API
type Kafka struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta   `json:",inline"`
    metav1.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty"`
    Spec   KafkaSpec   `json:"spec,omitempty"`
    Status KafkaStatus `json:"status,omitempty"`
}
```

Struct `Spec` which is child of `Kafka`.

```
// Spec defines the desired state of KafkaBundle
type Spec struct {
    // INSERT ADDITIONAL SPEC FIELDS - desired state of cluster
    // Important: Run "make" to regenerate code after modifying this file
    Kafka          *KafkaSpec      `json:"kafka"`
    
    // Foo is an example field of Kafka. Edit Kafka_types.go to remove/update
    Foo string `json:"foo,omitempty"`
}
```

Struct `KafkaSpec` which is child of struct `Spec`

```
type KafkaSpec struct {
    Replicas int `json:"replicas"`
    Listeners *Listners
}
```

Similarly create a struct for `Plain` and `Authentication`.

I hope this solves your problem.